# MYSQL Query not returning expected records

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have 3 tables as shown below:

**subscription_plans**

[image]

**subscribed_videos**

[image]

**subscription_groups**

[image]

I want to find the plans corresponding to the selected video (table *subscription_plans*). Table *subscription_groups* contains the plan-plan mapping ie, a plan can be part of another plan. For example, Plan A, Plan B and Plan C. Plan A contains both Plan B an Plan C and video with id 5 is part of Plan B (table *subscribed_videos*) , then the query for finding the plans corresponding to video 5 should return Plan A along with Plan B. Also the records should be distinct.

I tried with the following query. But if I am adding a plan which don't have an entry in *subscription_groups*, then that record is not returning with this query.

```
$videoid=$_POST['videoid'];
echo "select sv.plan_id,sg.plan_id,sp.id,sp.plan,sp.days_limit,sp.rate from subscribed_videos as sv 
    LEFT JOIN subscription_groups as sg ON sv.plan_id=sg.assosiated_plan_id INNER JOIN 
    subscription_plans as sp ON sv.plan_id=sp.id where sg.assosiated_plan_id=sv.plan_id and sv.videoid=$videoid
    and sg.assosiated_plan_id=sp.id";
```

Can anyone help me to find the appropriate query for this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think subqueries make sense for this query. The first subquery selects the id of the plan of your video and the second subquery selects the ids of the associated plans.

```
SELECT 
    sp.id,
    sp.plan,
    sp.days_limit,
    sp.rate 
FROM 
    subscription_plans sp
WHERE 
    id IN (SELECT DISTINCT plan_id FROM subscribed_videos sv where sv.videoid = $videoid)
    OR id IN (SELECT DISTINCT assosiated_plan_id 
        FROM subscription_groups sg
        JOIN subscribed_videos sv ON sv.plan_id = sg.plan_id
        WHERE sv.videoid = $videoid)
```

Comment: @Fuzzy..It is showing error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Comment: @Jenz updated the query to allow multiple rows in the subquery (IN instead of '=')